# Retonar varios itens de uma relação - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Estou com um pequeno problema, eu tenho uma relação de curso e aluno no sistema.

Criei uma função mostrar no controller e queria fazer com que ao clicar nos detalhes ele mostrasse todos os alunos cadastrados em um curso.
mostrar no CursoController

```
public function mostrar($id)
        {

            $alunos = Curso::whereHas('alunos')->with('alunos')->where('id', $id)->get();


            return view('curso.mostrar', compact('alunos'));

        }
```

E meu mostrar.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ action('CursoController@index') }}"> Voltar</a>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Cidade</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($alunos as $aluno)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$aluno->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$aluno->nome}}</td>
        <td>{{ $aluno->cidade }}</td>
        <td>{{ $aluno->estado}}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

O problema aqui é que ele está retornando o nome do curso ao envés da relação de alunos.

O meu model curso está assim

```
class Curso extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['professor_id', 'nome'];

    public function professor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Professor::class);
    }

    public function alunos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Aluno::class);
    }
}
```

Meu model de Aluno está assim

```
class Aluno extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['curso_id','nome','data_nascimento', 'cep', 'logradouro', 'numero', 'bairro', 'cidade', 'estado'];


    public function curso()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(\App\Curso::class);
        }
}
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

No fim foi resolvido assim:
CursoController

```
public function mostrar($id)
        {

            $curso = Curso::findOrFail($id);
            $alunos = $curso->alunos;
            return view('curso.mostrar', compact('curso', 'alunos'));

        }
```

E a rota

```
Route::get('cursos/{id}/mostrar', 'CursoController@mostrar');
```

Comment: Voce pode criar um metodo cursos dentro do Model do Aluno, e vice versa. Desta forma, cada aluno tera ->cursos assim como cada curso tera ->alunos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você utiliza:

> $alunos = Curso::whereHas('alunos')->with('alunos')->where('id', $id)->get();

Você está dizendo, busque os cursos com id = $id, e que possuem alunos (você não está fazendo o relacionamento).

Primeiro vamos ao CursoController.
Você pode passar por parâmetro já o curso.
na rota seria:

```
Route::get('/{curso}/mostrar', 'CursoController@mostrar');
```

No controller:

```
public function mostrar(Curso $curso){
    return view('curso.mostrar', compact('curso'));
}
```

Na view você poderá acessar os dados do curso como nome e outras informações, como também pode acessar os relacionamentos direto da view;

$curso->alunos
   $curso->professor

você pode utilizar também no controller o seguinte código:

```
public function mostrar(Curso $curso){
    $curso = $curso->load('alunos','professor');
    return view('curso.mostrar', compact('curso'));
}
```

assim você já tem o relacionamento carregado antes da blade.

Comment: Essa parte de carregar no controller me ajudou bastante

Answer (score 1):

Isso vai depender um pouco do relacionamento, mas isso pode ajudá-lo:

Model Cursos, considerando que há uma tabela AlunosCursos tratando os relacionamentos:

```
class Cursos extends
{
    public function alunos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('AlunosCursos', 'cursos_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Isso fará com que o Curso tenha o objeto alunos.

Então, seu controler pode simplesmente passar o Curso normalmente, e na view, você acessar os alunos.

Seu Controller:

```
public function mostrar($id)
{
   $curso = Curso::with('alunos')->where('id', $id)->get();
   return view('curso.mostrar', compact('curso'));
}
```

Na view:

```
{{ $curso->alunos }}
```

Me desculpe se faltou algo, se quiser postar mais detalhes de sua estrutura, pode me ajudar a sugerir algo.

---

Edit:

Vamos especificar manualmente as conexões.

Dê uma lida nas referências para clarear as idéias.

Altere no seu Model Aluno:

REF: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

```
public function curso()
{
   return $this->hasOne(\App\Curso::class, 'id', 'curso_id');
}
```

Altere no seu Model Cursos:

REF: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

```
public function alunos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Aluno::class, 'curso_id', 'id');
    }
```

Comment: Eu mostrei acima como estão os dois models do relacionamento, poderia dar uma analisada pra mim?

Comment: Eu não tenho essa tabela AlunoCursos

Comment: @LintonJunior, confere meu edit e confirme se funcionou

Comment: Olá, David.
Funcionou em partes, eu dei uma lida e consegui resolver, eu edito a primeira pergunta mostrando a solução?

Comment: Que otimo que conseguiu! Se minha resposta ajudou, marque como util :D

Comment: Eu nao sei se o ideal é voce lançar uma resposta completa ou editar o seu conteudo.