# PDF no Laravel retornando View selecionada

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5.4, dompdf

Olá, eu estou usando o DomPDF pra tentar retornar um relatório em pdf, porém todas as vezes que chamo a view ele fica carregando como se estivesse em um loop infinito e não acontece nada.
Segue meu código
CursoController.php

```
public function downloadPDF($id)
    {
      $curso = Curso::find($id);
      $alunos = $curso->alunos;
      $pdf = PDF::loadView('curso.pdf', compact('curso', 'alunos'));
      return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');

    }
```

A minha rota está chamando assim:

```
Route::get('/cursos/{id}/pdf','CursoController@downloadPDF');
```

E a view que eu quero chamar é pdf.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')


<div class="container">

<h2>{{$curso->nome}}</h2>

    <br>
    <div class="pull-right">
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Nascimento</th>
        <th>logradouro</th>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Bairro</th>
        <th>Cidade</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Dt. Criação</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($alunos as $value)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->nome}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->data_nascimento}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->logradouro}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->numero}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->bairro}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->cidade}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->estado}}</td>
        <td>{{ date( 'd/m/Y' , strtotime($value->created_at))}}</td>

      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>


@endsection
```

Consegui gerar o pdf colocando apenas um

## PDF GERADO

, agora preciso fazer ele retornar as variáveis.

Answer (score 1):

O que pode estar acontecendo, é alguma variável que é utilizada no seu master está atrapalhando a impressão do pdf.

tenta tirar o template, caso continue, tenta ir debugando o controller chamada por chamada, assim você teria uma certeza onde o erro está acontecendo.

Para debugar a view, comenta blocos e vê se ta saindo algum pdf.

Comment: O master não tem variável, ele é só a estrutura de início do html

Comment: Comenta tudo e deixa so um h1 com texto qualquer e vê se gerou texto, uso o mesmo código pra imprimir

Comment: Eu consegui fazer ele gerar o pdf sem nada na view, do jeito que o controller está, vou editar pra mostrar o controller, veja se pode me ajudar, ele tem um relacionamento e eu preciso chamar todos os itens

Comment: Olha, eu consegui retornar o nome do curso, porém não estou conseguindo retornar os alunos

Comment: O relacionamento de alunos com o curso está correto? as vezes é comum esquecer o return antes do $this->hasMany()

Lembrando que junto com o find($id) vc pode usar o with

$curso = Curso::find($id)->with("alunos");

e na view usar $curso->alunos para o foreach

Comment: Tá correntinha, to retornando no index

Comment: da uma olhada nesse link que eu fiz algumas considerações sobre relacionamento

[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286688/retonar-varios-itens-de-uma-rela%c3%a7%c3%a3o-laravel/286791#286791]

Comment: uma boa pratica no foreach é usar o $alunos as $aluno (para facilitar a orientação de que objeto você está usando